# How to change 1000.0 to 1000 in java excel import output?

Tags: java, log4j, apache-poi

I just got my code to work but the numbers in the excel sheet are not coming out the right way in the java console. For example the age should be 20 but it's coming out 20.0. Any suggestions?

Also, I am getting an error on my logger for some reason.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (package.JamaisDisplayMenu).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I have it set up the exact same way in another project and it works fine. Any ideas on that as well?

here is my code...

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;

public class JamaisDisplayMenu { 

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JamaisDisplayMenu.class); //starts logger

    public static void main( String [] args ) {

    try {

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
                   new FileInputStream("c:/Users/dude/Desktop/Data2.xls"));
       logger.error("File parsed");
       POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
       HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
       HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
    while( rows.hasNext() ) {  
        HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
        System.out.println("\n");
        Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
        while( cells.hasNext() ) {

            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
            if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC==cell.getCellType())
            System.out.print( cell.getNumericCellValue()+"     " );
            else
            if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==cell.getCellType())
                System.out.print( cell.getStringCellValue()+"     " );
            else
                if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN==cell.getCellType())
                System.out.print( cell.getBooleanCellValue()+"     " );
                else
                    if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK==cell.getCellType())
                        System.out.print( "BLANK     " );
                        else
                    System.out.print("Unknown cell type");
            logger.error("File parsed");
        }


    }


} catch ( IOException ex ) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method you are using returns a double value, you probably want either the floor of that value (for age), or a rounded value (if you wanted the price of something, perhaps to the nearest $)

Replace:

```
System.out.print( cell.getNumericCellValue()+"     " );
```

with:

`System.out.print( new Double(Math.floor(cell.getNumericCellValue())).intValue() +"     " );` for age

or

`System.out.print( new Double(cell.getNumericCellValue()+0.5).intValue() +"     " );` for rounding

Answer (score 1):

Formatting it without using the `POI` library works, like in gravityplanx answer shows. To get the exact format from the excel sheet, use the following

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
...
System.out.print(formatter.formatCellValue(cell)+"     " );
```

Read [DataFormatter doc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) for all the formatting that it permits.

Answer (score -1):

Consider adding the cell type to your debug output.  It's possible the cells in question are coming through as CELL_TYPE_STRING and you're getting preformatted text and not a number at all.  If that's the case, you'd have to fix it in excel (change the cell type).

Comment: CELL returns a double value regardless of what the original cell as in it.

Comment: No it doesn't.  If excel has stored the data as text then cell.getCellType() will return CELL_TYPE_STRING, and the OP's code will call cell.getStringCellValue() instead, which returns a **String**. https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html  Recommending to force it to an int is impractical because not all the data is necessarily going to be whole numbers, so code should respect the formatting saved in the spreadsheet.